Geometric Multiplicity of the Normal Cone.
Define the geometric multiplicity of an irreducible scheme $Z$ to be the length of ${\mathcal O}_{Z,Z}$, which is the algebra of functions localized at a generic point of $Z$ viewed as a module over itself. See Fulton’s intersection theory book Section 1.5.
Now let $X \hookrightarrow Y$ be a closed immersion from an irreducible scheme into a smooth scheme $Y$. For simplicity assume these schemes are defined over the complex numbers.
Let $C_{X/Y}$ be the normal cone of $X$ in $Y$, which by definition is $\text{Spec}(\oplus_{k = 0}^\infty {\mathcal I}^k/{\mathcal I}^{k+1})$ where ${\mathcal I}$ is the ideal sheaf defining $X$ in $Y$ pulled back to $X$.
Question: Does the geometric multiplicity of $X$ and $C_{X/Y}$ agree?
This is clearly not the case if $Y$ is not smooth. However, I am assuming $Y$ is smooth.
